# How do you replay multiple logs files in KDB

Tags: logging, kdb

When using -11! to replay log files, is it possible to iterate this over multiple files.

Simply using

```
-11!each listOfFiles
```

Returns an error.

I don't believe there is anything wrong with the underlying files, and have done individual replays to confirm they work. So just wanted to check if "each" should work in this context? or if there is some other suggested method.

I can only find examples of replaying an individual file so wondering if maybe this isn't supported.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your syntax is wrong, you want

```
(-11!)each listOfFiles

or

{-11!x}each listOfFiles
```